# Spark DataFrame aggregation

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code:

```
public class IPCCodes {

public static class IPCCount implements Serializable {
    public IPCCount(long permid, int year, int count, String ipc) {
        this.permid = permid;
        this.year = year;
        this.count = count;
        this.ipc = ipc;
    }

    public long permid;
    public int year;
    public int count;
    public String ipc;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("IPC codes");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    HiveContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc.sc());

    DataFrame df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM test.some_table WHERE year>2004");
    JavaRDD<Row> rdd = df.javaRDD();
    JavaRDD<IPCCount> map = rdd.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Row, IPCCount>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<IPCCount> call(Row row) throws Exception {
            List<IPCCount> counts = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                String codes = row.getString(7);
                for (String s : codes.split(",")) {
                    if(s.length()>4){
                        counts.add(new IPCCount(row.getLong(4), row.getInt(6), 1, s.substring(0, 4)));
                    }
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            return counts;
        }
    });
```

I created DataFrame from Hive table and apply flatMap function for splitting ipc codes (this field is array of string in hive table), after that I need aggregate codes with count per permid and year, result table should be permid/year/ipc/count.

What is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: I wouldn't `flatMap` in the first place. It should be easy to solve without leaving Spark SQL. But some details (like schema and example input) would be useful.

Comment: Table schema is (patnum string,pan string,assignee string,perm_assignee string,permid bigint,weight int,year int,ipc string,manualchem string,manualelec string,manualeng string,pubdate string,appdate string,expandclass string) 

data sample:
('AT83028261','1984170449','Some Company','SOME COMPANY CO',4295903113,64,2009,
'A61K000718,A61K000716,A61K000821','','','','','','')

Answer (score 3):

If you want a `DataFrame` as an output there is no good reason to use `RDD` and `flatMap`. As far as I can tell everything can be easily handled using basic Spark SQL functions. Using Scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, explode, length, split, substring}

val transformed = df
  .select(col("permid"), col("year"),
    // Split ipc and explode into multiple rows
    explode(split(col("ipc"), ",")).alias("code")) 
  .where(length(col("code")).gt(4)) // filter
  .withColumn("code", substring(col("code"), 0, 4))

transformed.groupBy(col("permid"), col("year"), col("code")).count
```

Comment: This perfectly works for me! Thanks! Also it encouraged me to use Scala instead of Java in my project.